# Story about children who gained abilities to interact with ghosts/spirits

Tags: ghost, story-identification

If I remember correctly, the book was about a group of kids playing a game which became real around them.

I think they each got a different power to deal with ghosts/spirits. If memory serves, one could talk to them, one could see them, and one could hear them. This meant that they had to work together.

It’s been at least 15 years since I read the book.

Comment: This is very sparse. Can you remember any part of the book title, character names, events that occurred, book length, when you read it, what kind of ghosts did they face, was it humorous or scary, etc?

Comment: I'm sorry for being sparse. I seriously have google searched this book to death. I remember it being more suspenseful than anything else. It has been at least 15 years since I have read it. :(

Comment: Can't help you with the book, but your first sentence is pretty much the synopsis for Jumanji...good luck

Comment: *Cursed: the Immortal* can't be the right one, since it came out in 2016, but "This story is about The Andersen family. They have a Paranormal business. They evacuate ghosts. There are three sisters, Andy, Dru and Eddy. One can hear ghosts, one can see ghosts and one can speak to ghosts. One brother named Trask who can't communicate with ghosts but is a people person and deals with clients" is a surprisingly close match.